# problem while extracting data from api in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

I have created an API to access data from the database. I have fetched the api data using axios and I want to display it. I have mapped the data, but it returns empty array for the first time.

```
const ExpenseList = () => {

    const [result, setResult] = useState([]);

    const expenseDetails = async () => {
        try {
          let res = await axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/expense");
          let result = res.data;
          setResult(result);
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
        }
      };

    
      useEffect(() => {
        expenseDetails()
      }, []);

      console.log("result", result)
    return (
        <Container className='list-group'>
            <Row className='title-row'>
                <Col className='title-col-expenses'>Expenses</Col>
            </Row>
            {
            result.map((items)=>{
                <ExpenseItem id={items.id} name={items.name} cost={items.cost} />
            })}
                
        </Container>
    )
}
```

I have attached a screenshot of console where I have logged "result"
[Click to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXO7s.png)

Comment: You're getting an empty array because in your useState... you're setting the initial value as an empty array :), and since axios is async, the first time you're getting the initial value, after the results are loaded, you're getting the actual array.

Comment: @CevaComic So what should I do to correct it?

Comment: Maybe set it as null as initial value, and instead of mapping the array, return a loading component while the value is null, or better, add an "isLoading" and set it to false, in your try catch, after the request is done.

Comment: @CevaComic I added isLoaded=false to the state response but it doesn't seem to make a difference

Answer (score 0):

as CevaComic said you are setting the initial value as an empty array.
useEffect will only work **after** the component has been rendered, so when you will console.log the data stored in result you will get the initial value.
Only after the component will render for the second time, because of the changed made inside setResult, the data from the api will be logged.

Comment: How do I make the component load when data is loaded?